# Cannot find out what is rendering a view block?

Tags: views, blocks, theming

I am working on an existing Drupal 7 website. I have a view that has a block display. The block is being displayed on some pages in the "second_sidebar" region. The mystery is that I cannot figure out how this block is being rendered/displayed in that region of those pages! In other words, the block is being added to the $page['sidebar_second'] variable, but cannot find how it is being included in that variable.

Please take into consideration the following facts:

- The block is not being assigned to any region in
  "admin/structure/block
- In the page.tpl.php, there is no inclusion of that block in the page['sidebar_second'] variable
- None of the theme templates are directly rendering that block

Comment: I meant to say in the second point that in the template.php file there is no inclusion of that block in the page['sidebar_second'] variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have just found out that the [Context](https://www.drupal.org/project/context) module is installed which was rendering the block on those pages.

The "Themer Info" should have indicated that somehow.

Answer (score 0):

Are you working on the right theme? How many theme's are installed? When you lock at admin/structure/block, how many theme's are mentioned under the title?

And: if you open the block, is there something in the tab 'pages'?

Comment: I am working on the right theme.